# we may assume that $J(A) = 0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

$k$ is a field with at least 3 elements. $A$ finite-dimensional $k$-algebra. Then $A$ has a $k$-basis consisting of invertible elements of $A$.

In the proof, the author shows first that the propertiy of having a basis consisting of invertible elements passes to direct products. It goes: let $A = B \times C$ and let $X,Y$ $k$-basis of $B,C$ in $B^\times, C^\times$. He showed that $A$ has $k$-basis in $A^\times$.Then he concludes we may assume that $A$ is indecomposable. I get this point.

Next, he says since $1 + J(A) \subseteq A^{\times}$, if follows that the $k$-span of $A^{\times}$ contains $J(A)$, and therefore we may assume that $J(A) = 0$. So A is semisimple and indecomposable, hence is isomorphic to $M_n(k) \otimes _k D$ for some integer $n$ and some f-d division algebra $D$. Hence follows the final conclusion.

I don't quite follow why we could make the second assumption. Any hints would be appreciated!

Comment: what is $J(A)$ ?

Comment: Jacobson radical. thx!

Comment: @TsemoAristide I'd presume it's the Jacobson radical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$J(A/J(A))=0$. Suppose that the result true for $J(A)=0$, it is true for $A/J(A)$, Let $p:A\rightarrow A/J(A)$ the quotient map, suppose that $p(x)$ is invertible, $p(x)p(y)=1$ implies that $xy=1+a,a\in J(A)$ and $xy\in 1+J(A)$ is invertible, $x,y$ are invertible.

If Let $x\in A$, $p(x)=\sum p(a_i), p(a_i)$ invertible implies that $x=\sum a_i+a,a\in J(A)$, $a_i$ is invertible and $a$ is in $Span(A^\times).$

Comment: Hello! Sorry, I have a follow-up question. Would it always work if we assume $J(A) = 0$ and hence $A$ is semisimple?

Comment: yes, it always works if $J(A)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

If $a\in J(A)$ then $a=(1+a)+(-1)$ and both $1+a$ and $-1$ are elements of $A^\times$.

Comment: Hi Angina! I get your equation. But how this allows the assumption? all the info of $J(A)$ is contained in $A^\times$?

Comment: It wasn't clear exactly what your question is. I have proved that the $k$-span of the elements of $A^\times$ contains $J(A)$. If that wasn't your question, please edit your question to clarify. @stevengerrard

Comment: ok. I am adding some more info.